# Built-in/portable method of appending string to file via bash without redirection

Tags: linux, bash, macos, io, freebsd

I've got a `debug()` function written in bash which aims to:

1. be portable across GNU linux boxes and MacOS
2. be usable inside loops such as `while ...; do ...; done < foo` where redirection is used
3. write messages to `/dev/stderr` OR a log file specified by `$DEBUG_LOG`

At present, it basically follows the (simplified) format:

```bash
# @description Write debug messages to $DEBUG_LOG if set, else /dev/stderr
# @usage debug <message>
function debug() {
    if [[ "${DEBUG}" == "true" ]]; then
        # Use $DEBUG_LOG if set, else /dev/stderr
        local log_file="${DEBUG_LOG:-/dev/stderr}"

        # Join all arguments using \n and prepend every line with "[debug] "
        local debug_message=$(printf "%s\n" "${@}" | sed 's/^/[debug] /')

        # Append the debug message to the log file
        echo "${debug_message}" | dd of="${log_file}" conv=notrunc oflag=append status=none
    fi
}
```

[image: debug example]

*[full code](https://github.com/shitchell/code/blob/main/sh/lib/debug.sh) for the curious*

### Main problem

The obvious `echo "${debug_message}" >> "${log_file}"` isn't an option. It fails on scenario #2. When `debug foo` is called inside a `while ... done < file.txt` loop, using redirection inside the `debug()` function will eat STDIN and break the loop.

From that, I've determined that I need some command that I can instead *pipe* to and append to either a log file or STDERR, and `dd` worked great until I tried using it on MacOS  Apparently the BSD version of `dd` doesn't allow the `oflag=append` option, which is fairly crucial for appending to a log file...

---

## Ideal solution

Ideally, there would be some basic command `append-stuff` such that I can do one of the following **without** redirection:

```bash
echo "${debug_message}" | append-stuff "${DEBUG_LOG:-/dev/stderr}"
append-stuff "${debug_message}" "${DEBUG_LOG:-/dev/stderr}"
```

---

## Approaches examined thus far

```bash
debug_message=$'hello world\nsome |[]& weird ch4r4ct3r$!\nfoo bar'
```

### sed

I've tried variations on:

```bash
sed -e '$a '"${debug_message}" "${DEBUG_LOG:-/dev/stderr}"
# sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unterminated `s' command

sed -e '$a helloworld' /dev/stderr
# hangs

echo "${debug_message}" | sed -e '$r /dev/stdin' "${DEBUG_LOG:-/dev/stderr}"
# hangs
```

### awk -i inplace

I've played with a few different variations of `echo "${debug_message}" | awk -i inplace ... /dev/stdin ... /dev/stderr`, but they all either printed warnings and/or hung the shell. More importantly, the inplace extension doesn't seem to be built-in / portable.

### dd

```bash
echo "${debug_message}" \
  | dd of="${DEBUG_LOG:-/dev/stderr}" conv=notrunc oflag=append status=none
# works, but oflag=append is not available on MacOS, and there doesn't seem
# to be an equivalent flag in the BSD version of dd
```

---

I don't know if there's a suitable `append-stuff` sort of command like I'm looking for that's either built-in to bash or part of the standard suite of *nix tools one can reasonably expect to find on any box, but if someone here knows of such a thing, I'd super appreciate it

Comment: `When debug foo is called inside a while ... done < file.txt loop, using redirection inside the debug() function will eat STDIN and break the loop.` This is only true if the content of the debug function reads stdin. `echo "${message}" >> "${file}"` does not read stdin in any way. Do you have a reproducible example of this? If your stdin is being eaten by something else then fixing that and using redirections may be the simplest path forward.

Comment: Copy/pasteable example: `f() { echo "$1" >> testfile ; } ; while read -r line ; do f "$line" ; done < <( printf '%s\n' foo bar baz )`. All three lines appear in the file, no exhaustion of stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own example

```
#! /bin/bash

# @description Write debug messages to $DEBUG_LOG if set, else /dev/stderr
# @usage debug <message>
function debug() {
    if [[ "${DEBUG}" == "true" ]]; then
        # Use $DEBUG_LOG if set, else /dev/stderr
        local log_file="${DEBUG_LOG:-/dev/stderr}"

        # Join all arguments using \n and prepend every line with "[debug] "
        local debug_message=$(printf "%s\n" "${@}" | sed 's/^/[debug] /')

        # Append the debug message to the log file
        #echo "${debug_message}" | dd of="${log_file}" conv=notrunc oflag=append status=none
        echo "${debug_message}" >> "${log_file}"
    fi
}


DEBUG=true
DEBUG_LOG=$(mktemp)

yes | head -5 > foo

i=5
while (( i > 0 )); do
    debug "$i"
    read f
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
    (( i-- ))
done < foo

cat "$DEBUG_LOG"
rm "$DEBUG_LOG"
```

and you'll see the debug messages

```
[debug] 5
[debug] 4
[debug] 3
[debug] 2
[debug] 1
```

printed.

Comment: Wouldn't `printf "[debug] %s\n" "${@}"` work just as well?